# Markdown: todo list not Showing in Jupyter Notebook Cell in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown

On the [github.docs](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/about-task-lists) I saw that it is possible to create markdown todo-lists as follows

```markdown
- [ ] my first task
- [ ] my second task
```

When I am trying this in VSCode in a `.ipynb` Markdown cell, it doesn't render the todo-list. So it basically does not show rendered square but rather shows it just as I typed it in. So it does show it as this

[image]

but not as this

[image]

I am using the [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension for VSCode.

I think it has to do something with this extension. However, rendering a table for example works. Also including pictures and basically any other Markdown command I tried. Only the todo-list does not.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33755), VSCode does not support markdown todo-lists out of the box. However, you can use the [Markdown Checkbox extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.markdown-checkbox), which renders todo-lists in `.ipynb` Markdown cells.

For reference, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAOR4.png) is what the result looks like.